# Calling C# com object from c++, who should free the memory?

Tags: c#, c++, com

For ex. i have c# COM object with such function:

```
int GetString([In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]ref string str)
```

then i'm calling int from c++ (in c++ COM object is used via `#import` keyword), in generated wrapper method is declared as:

```
GetString(LPSTR * str, long * retVal)
```

i'm calling it this way:

```
char myStr[40];
LPSTR buf = (LPSTR)myStr;
LPSTR pBuf = &buf;

pComObject->GetString(pBuf);
```

what is strange:

1) myStr is not filled, and `buf` value is changed (it doesnt the same with `myStr` after the call) so, i suppose that c# marshaller allocates new block of memory

2) if c# allocates memory so should i call `free(buf);` or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the client should release the memory.
In this case, one should use the [CoTaskMemFree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to free the received buffer. Since the buffer may not be allocated on the client's heap. CoTaskMemFree will call an appropriate deleter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think that you do need to free the buffer in your C++ code after calling the GetString function.

According to the [COM "Memory Management Rules"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the caller (your C++ code) should free memory that is returned as an output parameter.  In the case of an input/output parameter, the callee (the CLR and your C# code) may free the memory of the parameter that you passed in and then allocate new memory for the output value, and it is again the caller's responsibility to free that memory.

Comment: Upvoted! Good explanation, and I should have mentioned the rules.